# Setting threshold for the database

Tags: python, numpy, analytics, outliers

So. I have a database. Among it there are two columns, I have made a graph with. When it appeared - I noticed some outliers, which a little bit interfere me. [1st graph with the outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8lKl.png) . I am using this columns total_day_minutes, total_day_charge. How can I remove them? Is it possible to give an answer jugging by this picture. Thank you)

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=[18, 6])  # define a plot with 3 Axes (day, eve, night)
df.plot(kind='scatter', 
        x='total_day_minutes', 
        y='total_day_charge', 
        ax=axs[0],
        xlim=(0,500),
        ylim=(0,60));  # check day columns
df.plot(kind='scatter', 
        x='total_eve_minutes', 
        y='total_eve_charge', 
        ax=axs[1],
        xlim=(0,500),
        ylim=(0,60));  # check evening columns
df.plot(kind='scatter', 
        x='total_night_minutes', 
        y='total_night_charge', 
        ax=axs[2],
        xlim=(0,500),
        ylim=(0,60));  # check night columns
```